# Laravel - Not unique table/alias on Polymorphic Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have three tables, they are :

**Contacts**

- contact_name
- contact_email
- contact_phone

**Locations**

- location_name
- location_country

**Association Contacts**

- association_contact_id
- association_contacts_id
- contacts_type

In my models, I've set the Polymorphs...

**AssociationContact**

```
public function contact()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

**Client**

```
public function contact()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(
    // the related model
        'App\Models\AssociationContact',
        // the relationship name
        'contact',

        // the table name, which would otherwise be derived from the relationship name - twowordables
        'association_contacts',

        // the foreign key will be twowordable_id, derived from the relationship name, which you're adhering to
        'association_contact_id',

        // the 'other' key, which would otherwise be derived from the related model's snake case name - two_word_id
        'association_contacts_id'
    );
}
```

When running the following code :

```
$clients = Client::all();
foreach($clients as $client)
{
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($client->contact);
  echo "</pre>";
}
```

I get the following error :

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'association_contacts' (SQL: select `association_contacts`.*, `association_contacts`.`association_contact_id` as `pivot_association_contact_id`, `association_contacts`.`association_contacts_id` as `pivot_association_contacts_id`, `association_contacts`.`contact_type` as `pivot_contact_type` from `association_contacts` inner join `association_contacts` on `association_contacts`.`id` = `association_contacts`.`association_contacts_id` where `association_contacts`.`association_contact_id` = 7 and `association_contacts`.`contact_type` = App\Models\Client)
```

It must be how I've set up the model relations, But not sure what I've done wrong.

Cheers

Comment: The 3`d argument should be 'contacts' ?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in **AssociationContact**:

```
public function contact()
{
    return $this->morphTo(null,'contacts_type','association_contacts_id');
}
```

Change the relationship in your **Client** table to this:

```
public function contact()
{
     return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Contact','contact','contacts_type','association_contacts_id');
    }
```

This should work.

Comment: Returns this :

Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'contacts.association_contacts' in 'where clause'

Comment: New Error : Unknown column 'contacts.contact_type' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `contacts` where `contacts`.`contact_id` = 7 and `contacts`.`contact_id` is not null and `contacts`.`contact_type` = App\Models\Client)

Comment: It usually very helpful to have intuitive names for your relationships.